# Set background color for specific cell in Markdown table

Tags: markdown

Consider the Markdown table given below:

```
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---|---|---|
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
| 7 | 8 | 9 |
```

I wish to set the background color to red for a specific cell, e.g. cell 8. I found a forum that discussed how one could use HTML to set the font color, but nothing about setting the actual cell background color.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The background-color is a part of the style. Markdown is only for content and structure.

But you can use [css selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

- if you can use css3: `td:nth-child(n)`
- with css2: `td + td` and overwrite it again `td + td + td`

[Both versions with your example](http://jsfiddle.net/mraLrgp2/)

Comment: So what would this markup look like considering the example table?

Answer (score 30):

I found an example of Markdown table styling [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kaushalmodi/ox-hugo/master/test/site/content/posts/table-styling.md) that worked with Microsoft Visual Studio Code preview.

The following example gives this result:

[image: demo]

```
## Table Styling in Markdown

<style>
    .heatMap {
        width: 70%;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .heatMap th {
        background: grey;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .heatMap tr:nth-child(1) { background: red; }
    .heatMap tr:nth-child(2) { background: orange; }
    .heatMap tr:nth-child(3) { background: green; }
</style>

<div class="heatMap">

| Everything | in this table | is Centered | and the table will only take up 70% of the screen width | 
| -- | -- | -- | -- |
| This | is | a | Red Row |
| This | is | an | Orange Row |
| This | is | a | Green Row |

</div>
```

Comment: Note that this would not work with github wiki which (at least as of now) does not allow custom styles 
https://github.com/gollum/gollum/issues/618

Comment: I like this solution, it worked. How can I color according to a column value? For example, using the last column of the example to color it.

Comment: Ah, back to CSS and HTML. Honestly, I though this Markdown language is a bit more of a shorthand. Essentially, the markdown is still converted to HTML - no native browser support. I guess it is not that developed. It appears it would benefit from a transpiler, so that new features can be developed more rapidly.