# How can I add a colored square in a table using Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I need to create a table with a square or a rectangle, in a table, preferably, for a markdown code to show in the README.
There is a way that I can do something like bellow.

| code | color |
| --- | --- |
| #0F0 | [Green Square here] |
| #F00 | [Red Square here] |

Comment: You have to create your own style to make a table like this. Check the linked article: https://nabeelvalley.co.za/blog/2021/23-03/custom-styles-in-markdown/ or as described / shown in this stackoverflow page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26197579/set-background-color-for-specific-cell-in-markdown-table

Comment: @Siloe you mean on GitHub or using what markdown processor?

Comment: Yes, my intention is to use in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

You could use tables from [GitHub-flavoured Markdown (GFM)](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#tables) and combine them with plain HTML styles for coloring. You could use [HTML encoding for special symbols](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_geometric.asp) to display a square symbol like ◼ (`&#9724;`) or ◻ (`&#9723;`).

The result in Markdown could be something like the following. But I didn't test that on GitHub.com

```
| code  | color                                           |
| :---- |:------------------------------------------------|
| #0F0  | <span style="color:rgb(0,200,0)">&#9724;</span> |
| #F00  | <span style="color:rgb(200,0,0)">&#9724;</span> |
```